# WPF | MultiDataTrigger and Binding to the same property

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, binding

I'm working on the next task.
There are some class and enum:

```
public enum Status
{
   Running,
   Canceled,
   Failed,
   Completed  
}

public class Result
{
   public Status Status { get; set; }

   public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

And I have some UI control with the button. This button should do a few things:

1. It should be enabled only in cases when Status == Completed, IsActive = false;
2. When the user presses the button, it should be disabled (and IsActive should be true);
3. In some cases the Result object can be null, so the button should be disabled.

To do this, I was trying to create the MultiDataTrigger with Status and IsActive and set the Binding to the IsActive (for the case when the user presses the button -> we set Enabled = false -> binding set IsActive = true).
Also, I found that the Binding has the property TargetNullValue, which is used for the button when the Result object is null.
And I used Mode=OneWayToSource for the Binding because when I change the IsEnabled property it should change only the IsActive property.

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding IsActive, Mode=OneWayToSource, Converter=BooleanInvertedConverter, TargetNullValue = false}">
   <Button.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
         <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
               <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition Property="{Binding Status}" Value="Status.Completed"/>
                  <Condition Property="{Binding IsActive, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue=false}" Value="False"/>
               </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
               <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

In case when I try to run this code it shows me the exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

I think it happens because at this moment Result object is null, but I try to set some value in his IsActive property by the Binding. If I remove the Binding and leave only the trigger - all work, button reacts on the initial values of the IsActive and Status properties. But when I press the button, nothing happened, because there is no Binding, and IsActive wasn't changed.

So it seems that this Binding shouldn't try to set the value in cases when the Result object is null. But even if the Result object is null the button still should be disabled according to the TargetNullValue=false in the trigger.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: In WPF, the typical solution for this kind of problem is to use a command in a button and handle the dependencies to enable the button in the command's CanExecute method.

Comment: You should always implement inotifypropertychanged in any viewmodel. Result is a viewmodel here.

Comment: You are binding isenabled AND trying to set it using a trigger. Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: As eldhasp says though, you should be using icommand here.

Answer (score 0):

Without an example that can be performed on my computer, it’s hard for me to say exactly why. But there are a few obvious mistakes.

1. If you set a property value (directly or by binding), then that value takes precedence over the value from the Style. In your case, this means style triggers will be ignored.
2. Since a binding error is possible, you need to set the return value in case of such an error.
3. In `Condition` you need to specify not `Property`, but `Binding`.

Here is an implementation that might solve your problem:

```xml
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Status, FallbackValue=Failed}" Value="Completed"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue=True}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

**P.S.** In WPF, the typical solution for this kind of problem is to use a command in a button and handle the dependencies to enable the button in the command's CanExecute method.

> But when I press button and programmatically set Button.IsEnabled=false, the breakpoint in the SET of the IsActive property doesn't work.

```cs
    public class ResultToIsEnabledConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private ResultToIsEnabledConverter()
        { }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values?.Length != 2 ||
                values[0] is not bool isActive ||
                values[1] is not Status status)
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

            return !isActive && status == Status.Completed;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object[] values = Enumerable.Repeat(Binding.DoNothing, targetTypes.Length).ToArray();
            if (value is bool isEnabled && !isEnabled)
                values[0] = true;

            return values;
        }

        public static ResultToIsEnabledConverter Instance { get; } = new();
    }
```

```cs
    public class ResultToIsEnabledBinding : MultiBinding
    {
        private static readonly Binding bindingIsActive = new Binding()
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath(typeof(Result).GetProperty(nameof(Result.IsActive))),
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            FallbackValue = true
        };
        private static readonly Binding bindingStatus = new Binding()
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath(typeof(Result).GetProperty(nameof(Result.Status))),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            FallbackValue = Status.Failed
        };
        public ResultToIsEnabled()
        {
            Converter = ResultToIsEnabledConverter.Instance;
            FallbackValue = false;
            Bindings.Add(bindingIsActive);
            Bindings.Add(bindingStatus);
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class ResultFallbackBinding : Binding
    {
        private static readonly Result result = new Result();
        public ResultFallbackBinding()
        {
            FallbackValue = result;
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        }
    }
```

```xml
<Button DataContext="{local:ResultFallbackBinding}"
        IsEnabled="{local:ResultToIsEnabledBinding}"/>
```

Style and triggers are not needed. They can only provide unidirectional communication.

Comment: Do I need to set Mode=TwoWay for the IsActive condition in this case? Because when I set the Button.IsEnabled=false, it also should set some value to the IsActive. But how it will do without binding?

Comment: I tried your implementation. It works only for the UI. But when I press button and programmatically set Button.IsEnabled=false, the breakpoint in the SET of the IsActive property doesn't work.

Comment: I fixed this problem. Mb is not very elegantly, but it working.
I set the Result object as the DataContext of a button. And instead of setting the Button.IsEnabled=false I set (Button.DataContext as Result).IsActive=true. And after that trigger was raised to update the IsEnabled property. So I have the correct UI state and correct value in the IsActive property.